# External function in NSPredicate

Tags: swift, xcode, location, nspredicate, predicate

I'm trying to use an external function in declaring a condition inside the NSPredicate object.

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "@min(distanceBetween(%@,%@))", place1.cllocation, place2.cllocation)
```

How can I do it? I have to calculate the distance between two CLLocations. The syntax is: `dist = place2.cllocation.distance(from: place1.cllocation)`

I'm using Xcode 8.2 and writing in Swift 3.

Comment: You are using `@min` which works on arrays of data, however you seem to only have a single value - the distance between two `CLLocation` objects. What, exactly, are you attempting to accomplish here? Can you include more code around your issue?

Comment: The second location (e.g. my current location) is constant. place1 should be counted as every location and then find the minimum of all distances.

Comment: So `place1` is of type [CLLocation], is that correct? What is the signature for `distanceBetween`?

Comment: What do you mean by signature?

Comment: With this query, I would like to find the closest place to my current location. It should check distance between me and every place in database and then find minimal value (@min)

Comment: `distanceBetween` is a function and it is defined somewhere. The signature is the parameters it takes, the names, types, return values, etc.

Comment: If you don't use CoreData, you can use a NSPredicate with Block/closure.

Comment: this function takes 2 locations and returns a distance (float or smth)

Comment: I recommend you take some time to reformat this question, it is unclear as to the code you are using and how you expect it to accomplish the task. Include actual code and not descriptions of how a function works, if possible.

Comment: Are you making an `NSFetchRequest` here?

Comment: Documentation of `NSPredicate`: "The NSPredicate class is used to define logical conditions used to constrain a search either for a fetch or for in-memory filtering.". `@min` isn't a logical condition. Fetch all objects and then calculate the closest place. Core Data can't use custom functions in fetch requests.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I thought it's possible to fetch data with custom function - there is a lot of data and I wanted to speed the search up.